# Guard doesn't run on changes on spec/features/login_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I have a Rails 3.2 app with a file `spec/features/login_spec.rb`. I'm trying – without luck – to get Guard to run when this file is changed.

Here's my `Guardfile`:

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch(%r{^spec/factories/(.+)\.rb$})                { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
end


guard 'spork', :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch('config/environments/test.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { :rspec }
end
```

When I change files in `spec/models/`, or `spec/support/`, it picks up the changes and re-runs. It's just `spec/features/' that's no good. It doesn't seem to be Rspec's fault, as running`rspec` runs those files (and thus so does hitting [enter] in the Guard console).

And when I change the name of the file to anything (well, anything I've tried) besides `login_spec.rb`, it gets picked up.

So why does Guard have a dislike for this filename? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it was a [bug](https://github.com/guard/listen/issues/144) in Guard that was fixed 9 Oct 2013.